# how to make this script works with two or more variables?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

```
function EnumerateWindows(hWnd: HWND; lparam:LPARAM):Bool;
var
  ClassName, TheText : Array [0..255] of char;
  sName : string;
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  GetClassNAme(hWnd,Classname, 255);
  if GetWindowText(hWnd, TheText, 255) > 0 then
  begin
    sName := StrPas(TheText);
    if pos('NOTEPAD',UpperCase(sName)) > 0 then
      postMessage(FindWindow(ClassName, TheText), WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
  end;
end;
```

the question is i want to make double variables in if condition besides "NOTEPAD" like i would like to add "CHROME" as well or other variable. is it possible?

i already tried by use this syntax

```
if pos('NOTEPAD' + 'CHROME',UpperCase(sName)) > 0 then
if pos('NOTEPAD' or 'CHROME',UpperCase(sName)) > 0 then
```

but it is not work
thank you.

**NEW CASE**
*so i got problem while trying to connected the TEdit value into if condition.*
here's my full code it works and already compiled but got forced close when software is running and showed an error like this
Project project1.exe raised exception class eaaccesviolation with message 'acces violation at addres 0000000' read of addres 0000000' process stopped use top or run to continue

my code

```
public
    { Public declarations }
    function EnumerateWindows(hWnd: HWND; lparam:LPARAM):Bool; stdCall;
  end;

function TForm1.EnumerateWindows(hWnd: HWND; lparam:LPARAM):Bool;
var
  ClassName, TheText : Array [0..255] of char;
  sName : string;
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  GetClassNAme(hWnd,Classname, 255);
  if GetWindowText(hWnd, TheText, 255) > 0 then
  begin
    sName := StrPas(TheText);
    if pos(Edt1.Text,UpperCase(sName)) > 0 then
      postMessage(FindWindow(ClassName, TheText), WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 EnumWindows(@TForm1.EnumerateWindows,0);
end;
```

Comment: If `P` and `Q` are two boolean expressions, then `P or Q` is their disjunction. In other words, `if (Pos('NOTEPAD', UpperCase(sName)) > 0) or (Pos('CHROME', UpperCase(sName)) > 0) then`. But you really, really shouldn't be doing advanced stuff (like using the Win32 API) before you know the absolute basics of Pascal!

Comment: hi thank you for the reply. i don't quite understand since i'm new. but thank you i'm trying to understand it.

Comment: You should consider buying a good introductory book about programming in Delphi.

Comment: FYI, the call to `FindWindow()` is redundant, since you already have the HWND that you are searching for, so just use the HWND as-is. `postMessage(FindWindow(ClassName, TheText), ...);` => `postMessage(hWnd, ...);`

Comment: alright. thanks for the advise, i'm considering buying it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : thanks for the reply. when i changed it i got error.. i don't know but.. is the way to do that by use findwindow really bad?

Comment: @FahleviMikase what is the actual error? It is redundant since you adjust have the HWND, but also bad because it might find a different window if there are multiple windows open that have the same class and title

Comment: @RemyLebeau, hi, i got a new question if you wouldn't mind.. can you help to answer it? so i want connect the edit1.text with variable in if condition. is there any way for it? i tried if pos(edt1.text but it is not work

Comment: @FahleviMikase you can use the callback's `lParam` parameter to pass in a pointer to the Edit control. BTW, your callback needs to have the `stdcall` calling convention added to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i'm sorry i don't quite understand. and i also already looking for some source to able understand that but i couldn't qwq could you give me some example? i tried to declarate them to public TFORM1.Function and i got no error but when the software is running. it force closed with some error code

Comment: @FahleviMikase please [edit] your question to show the code you have tried that is not working for you

Comment: @RemyLebeau allright. i already edited the post.

Comment: @FahleviMikase you can't use a **non-static** class method for the `EnumWindows()` callback, because of the hidden `Self` parameter. You need to make the callback `static`, or use a free-standing function, to get rid of that parameter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau *noted. thanks a lot btw for taking a time to help me about it. i really be honored. have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

If P and Q are two boolean expressions, then P or Q is their disjunction. In other words, `if (Pos('NOTEPAD', UpperCase(sName)) > 0) or (Pos('CHROME', UpperCase(sName)) > 0) then.` But you really, really shouldn't be doing advanced stuff (like using the Win32 API) before you know the absolute basics of Pascal!

by : https://stackoverflow.com/users/282848/andreas-rejbrand